# Map array in descending order of the sum of the elements of an array

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```json
{
"user": [
   {"username": "x1", "pfp": "", "scores": [{"easy": 10, "normal": 1, "hard": 2, "oni": 3, "uraoni": 4}]},
   {"username": "x2", "pfp": "", "scores": [{"easy": 3, "normal": 1, "hard": 2, "oni": 3, "uraoni": 4}]},
   {"username": "x3", "pfp": "", "scores": [{"easy": 5, "normal": 1, "hard": 2, "oni": 3, "uraoni": 4}]},
   {"username": "x4", "pfp": "", "scores": [{"easy": 0, "normal": 40, "hard": 2, "oni": 3, "uraoni": 4}]}
]
}
```

Expected output of the order by username: `x4, x1, x3, x2` (x4 would have a value of 49, x1 a value of 20, x2 a value of 15 and x3 a value of 13).

and I need to map() the array in the order of the sum of the scores array.

I tried doing a map for reduce() the scores and then sort() it but it didn't let me reduce() it.

```js
let userscopy = userjson
  userscopy.map((user) => (
    user.scores[0] = JSON.parse(user.scores).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
  ))
```

[image: The error in question]
Any ideas?

Comment: Please show what you've tried

Comment: I tried doing a map for reduce() the scores and then sort() it but it didn't let me reduce() it.

Comment: Add what you've tried to the question as an edit :)

Comment: @Cerrebe edit your question an add your attempt in there and your expected result

Comment: can you please share expected output

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You've probably already parsed the JSON; no need to do it twice. Remove `JSON.parse(...)`

Comment: The parse remove actually worked, now it doesn't throw an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an helper function `total` and `sort` by it:

```js
const data = {
  user: [
    {
      username: 'x1',
      pfp: '',
      scores: [{ easy: 10, normal: 1, hard: 2, oni: 3, uraoni: 4 }],
    },
    {
      username: 'x2',
      pfp: '',
      scores: [{ easy: 3, normal: 1, hard: 2, oni: 3, uraoni: 4 }],
    },
    {
      username: 'x3',
      pfp: '',
      scores: [{ easy: 5, normal: 1, hard: 2, oni: 3, uraoni: 4 }],
    },
    {
      username: 'x4',
      pfp: '',
      scores: [{ easy: 0, normal: 40, hard: 2, oni: 3, uraoni: 4 }],
    },
  ],
};

const total = (user) => {
  if (user.scores.length === 0) return 0;
  const { easy, normal, hard, oni, uraoni } = user.scores[0];
  return easy + normal + hard + oni + uraoni;
};

const res = data.user.sort((a, b) => total(b) - total(a));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need by chance?

```
const userjson = {
  "user": [{
      "username": "x",
      "pfp": "",
      "scores": [{
        "easy": 0,
        "normal": 1,
        "hard": 2,
        "oni": 3,
        "uraoni": 4
      }]
    },
    {
      "username": "x",
      "pfp": "",
      "scores": [{
        "easy": 0,
        "normal": 1,
        "hard": 2,
        "oni": 3,
        "uraoni": 4
      }]
    },
    {
      "username": "x",
      "pfp": "",
      "scores": [{
        "easy": 0,
        "normal": 1,
        "hard": 2,
        "oni": 3,
        "uraoni": 4
      }]
    },
    {
      "username": "x",
      "pfp": "",
      "scores": [{
        "easy": 0,
        "normal": 1,
        "hard": 2,
        "oni": 3,
        "uraoni": 4
  }]
}
```

]
}

`1-` .map() only works with arrays so instead of `userjson.map()` use `userjson.user.map()` since the array is inside the user property

`2-` Remove the JSON.parse() since is not a valid json at the moment

`3-` use index for your `x.scores[i]`

```
const result = userjson.user.map((x,i) => (
    x.scores[i] = x.scores.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
  ))
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is not what I needed exactly, however it's already solved, but thanks for your time anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
"user": [
   {"username": "x1", "pfp": "", "scores": [{"easy": 10, "normal": 1, "hard": 2, "oni": 3, "uraoni": 4}]},
   {"username": "x2", "pfp": "", "scores": [{"easy": 3, "normal": 1, "hard": 2, "oni": 3, "uraoni": 4}]},
   {"username": "x3", "pfp": "", "scores": [{"easy": 5, "normal": 1, "hard": 2, "oni": 3, "uraoni": 4}]},
   {"username": "x4", "pfp": "", "scores": [{"easy": 0, "normal": 40, "hard": 2, "oni": 3, "uraoni": 4}]}
]
};

const order = data.user
  .sort((a, b) => addScores(b.scores[0]) - addScores(a.scores[0]))
  .map(({ username }) => username);

console.log(order);

function addScores(scores) {
  return Object.values(scores).reduce((p, n) => p + n, 0);
}
```